# create slider from JButton

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

I have got **JTextField** and **JButton** on **JPanel**. And I want to add listener to **JButton**, so that when I press button and move mouse the textfield value starts to change(increase when I move mouse right, and decrease when I move mouse left). So it is something like slider. Here is code

```
 final JPanel panel=new JPanel();
 final JTextField text = new JTextField("10");
 JButton button=new JButton("f");
 panel.add(text);
 panel.add(button);

 button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(final MouseEvent evt){

        //here we add listener to read mouse position when mouse pressed on button
        panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){

                int x1 = evt.getXOnScreen();

                int x2;

                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){
                    // this method is never called
                    x2=e.getXOnScreen();
                    //increase(decrese) number in textfield by 1% for every moved pixel
                    double d = (x2-x1)*0.01+Double.parseDouble(text.getText());
                    text.setText(Double.toString(d));
                    x1=x2;

                                                    }


                                              });

                        }
       // now, when mouse released we should remove listener from panel
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(final MouseEvent evt){
            MouseListener[] ml = panel.getListeners(MouseListener.class);
            panel.removeMouseListener(ml[0]);


        }
    });
```

the problem is, that mouseMoved method of panelListener is never called. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `MouseMotionListener` to your button and use `mouseDragged`. The coordinates can be stored in a `Point` on a `MouseEvent` of `MouseListener.mousePressed()`. With that you don't need to add and remove the listeners:

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    final JTextField text = new JTextField("10");
    final JButton button = new JButton("f");
    panel.add(text);
    panel.add(button);
    final Point point1 = new Point();
    final Point point2 = new Point();
    button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void mousePressed(final MouseEvent evt) {
        point1.x = evt.getXOnScreen();
      }
    });
    button.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
      @Override
      public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        point2.x = e.getXOnScreen();
        double d = (point2.x - point1.x) * 0.01 + Double.parseDouble(text.getText());
        text.setText(Double.toString(d));
        point1.x = point2.x;
      }
      @Override
      public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
      }
    });
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
panel.addMouseMotionListener(...)
```

instead of:

```
panel.addMouseListener(...)
```

From [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html):

> **public interface MouseListener:** The listener interface for receiving "interesting" mouse events (press, release, click, enter, and exit) on a component. (To track mouse moves and mouse drags, use the MouseMotionListener.)